# Easy way to access nested properties in a Map

Tags: java, spring

I use the following code to access directly to any property in a structure of nested maps as in the example.

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor;
import org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource;

import java.util.Map;

public class MapPropertySourceLearningTest {

    @Test
    public void testFlattenedMap() {
        Map map = ImmutableMap.of(
                "meta", ImmutableMap.of(
                        "pagination", ImmutableMap.of(
                                "position", "1",
                                "itemsPerPage", "50",
                                "totalPages", "9",
                                "totalItems", "438"
                        )
                )
        );

        MapPropertySource source = new MapPropertySource("map", new YamlProcessor() {
            public Map<String, Object> flatten(Map<String, Object> source) {
                return super.getFlattenedMap(source);
            }
        }.flatten(map));

        Assert.assertEquals("1", source.getProperty("meta.pagination.position"));
        Assert.assertEquals("9", source.getProperty("meta.pagination.totalPages"));
    }


}
```

I don't like having to extend YamlProcessor class. ¿ Is there a better way to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either [PropertyUtils.getProperty](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#getProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) (returns an Object) or [BeanUtils.getProperty](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#getProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) (returns a String) in [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) would suit your needs.  They throw some unwieldy exceptions though, so you may want to make your own wrapper method that handles the exceptions as you see fit.

```
Assert.assertEquals("1", PropertyUtils.getProperty(map, "meta.pagination.position"));
Assert.assertEquals("9", PropertyUtils.getProperty(map, "meta.pagination.totalPages"));
Assert.assertEquals("1", BeanUtils.getProperty(map, "meta.pagination.position"));
Assert.assertEquals("9", BeanUtils.getProperty(map, "meta.pagination.totalPages"));
```